# Как сделать чтобы при клике по картинке она открывалась в полном размере (используя Picasso) ? Что я делаю не так?

Tags: android, adapter, gridview, picasso

Код адаптера:

```
public class FlowersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Flower> {
    public FlowersAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_flower, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Flower flower = getItem(position);

        holder.getTvName().setText(flower.getName());

        Picasso.with(getContext())
                .load(flower.getPhotoUrl())
                .into(holder.getIvPhoto());

        return convertView;
    }

    private final static class ViewHolder {
        private ImageView ivPhoto;
        private TextView tvName;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            ivPhoto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivPhoto);
            tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        }

        public ImageView getIvPhoto() {
            return ivPhoto;
        }

        public TextView getTvName() {
            return tvName;
        }
    }
}
```

Full Image код:

```
public class FullImage extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

        // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        int getPhotoUrl = i.getExtras().getInt("getPhotoUrl");

        ImageView getIvPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);

        Picasso.with(this) //
                .load(getPhotoUrl) //
                .into(getIvPhoto);
    }

}
```

Activity код:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener  {
    GridView gvFlowers;
    FlowersAdapter flowersAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        gvFlowers = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvFlowers);
        flowersAdapter = new FlowersAdapter(this);
        gvFlowers.setAdapter(flowersAdapter);
        for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
            flowersAdapter.add(new Flower("http://www.bollea.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/blush-pink-bouquet-th.jpg", "0"));
            flowersAdapter.add(new Flower("http://www.kwiaty.lublin.pl/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/bukiet-%C5%9Blubny-11-250x250.jpg", "2"));
            flowersAdapter.add(new Flower("http://litbimg8.rightinthebox.com/images/250x250/201503/qbzrsr1427266951513.jpg", "2"));
            flowersAdapter.add(new Flower("http://fs40.www.ex.ua/get/203280815/wXsJTXyBfUzVrbiuQX.jpg", "asd"));
            flowersAdapter.add(new Flower("http://www.bollea.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/pink-bouquet-th.jpg", "0"));
            flowersAdapter.add(new Flower("http://www.bollea.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/nice-bouquet-th1.jpg", "0"));
            flowersAdapter.add(new Flower("http://www.packageperfect.net/images/Product/medium/6193.jpg", "0"));
            flowersAdapter.add(new Flower("http://www.womenclub.ru/images/stories/fashion/wedding/Bridal_Bouquet_4.jpg", "0"));
            flowersAdapter.add(new Flower("http://www.bollea.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/blush-pink-bouquet-th.jpg", "0"));
            flowersAdapter.add(new Flower("http://www.bollea.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/blush-pink-bouquet-th.jpg", "0"));

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, FullImage.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, FullImage.class));
}
```

на

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent i = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, FullImage.class);
    i.putExtra("getPhotoUrl", flowersAdapter.getItem(position).getPhotoUrl() );
    startActivity(i);
}
```

и

```
int getPhotoUrl = i.getExtras().getInt("getPhotoUrl");
```

на

```
String getPhotoUrl = i.getStringExtra("getPhotoUrl");
```

Почему не работает сейчас:

1. Вы пытаетесь достать из интента то, что никогда в него не клали. Откуда он узнает, какую исенно `URL` вы хотите загрузить?
2. Вы достаете из интента `int`, и пытаетесь использовать его как `URL`. Вы когда-нибудь видели численные `URL`?

Метод

```
asso.with(this).load(int)
```

Загружает изображение из ресурсов приложения, где параметр - `id` изображения (`R.drawable.<имя картинки>`)ю

Comment: Спасибо, все верно! + я еще забыл добавить строку  "gvFlowers.setOnItemClickListener(this); " в Activity.